# Django rest framework, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data' and unable to upload image using forms

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, file-upload

I'm struggling with recruitment task, i'm pretty new in Django and I haven't used rest framework before.
I'm trying to built view where user can upload picture and set how long link should be valid(in range 3000-30000, validation works for that). This feature works thru postman instaed of received link to file I have  following error:

```
    return renderer.render(serializer.data, None, {'style': style})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

When I try to upload file using website serializer is not passing validation.

I'm using render_form in html file and result in QueryDict is different than in postman so i guess thats the issue, however no idea how to solve it:
using website:

```
'image_url': ['airplane.jpg'],
```

using postman:

```
 'image_url': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: airplane.jpg (image/jpeg)>]
```

models.py:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from images.validators import expiring_in_validator


def upload_to(instance, filename):
    unique_identify = str(int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()))
    return f"media/{filename}-{unique_identify}"

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
    expiring_within = models.IntegerField(validators=[expiring_in_validator])
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from images.models import Image


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['image_url', 'expiring_within']
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer

from images.serializers import PostSerializer


# Create your views here.
class AddImage(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    template_name = "add_image.html"
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    def get(self, request):
        serializer = PostSerializer()
        return Response({"serializer": serializer})

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(uploaded_by=self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

html:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
        {% render_form serializer %}

    <input type="submit" value="Wyślij">
</form>
```

Forms works now but after uploading image instead of link I'm having following traceback:(

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 56, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 220, in _get_response
> response = response.render()   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py",
> line 114, in render
> self.content = self.rendered_content   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py",
> line 70, in rendered_content
> ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)   File
> "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py",
> line 166, in render
> return template.render(context, request=request)   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
> line 61, in render
> return self.template.render(context)   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 175, in render
> return self._render(context)   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 167, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 1005, in render
> return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))   File
> "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 1005, in 
> return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))   File
> "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/library.py",
> line 237, in render
> output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)   File "/home/wojciech/PycharmProjects/thumbnail/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py",
> line 81, in render_form
> return renderer.render(serializer.data, None, {'style': style}) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data' [08/Mar/2023
> 09:59:08] "POST /uploadimage/ HTTP/1.1" 500 115861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the form, you need to add [`enctype`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) information to bind the file to the form, like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
        {% render_form serializer %}

    <input type="submit" value="Wyślij">
</form>
```

For the actual problem regarding `str object has no attribute data`, DRF documentation mentions that:

> Django rest framework looks for `render_form` template tag, to render Serializer.

The error is happening because in the html file it is looking for rendering the serializer using `render_form` tag. Since you are passing the serializer as `serializer` context variable, you need to send the serializer in post method like this:

```
   if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(uploaded_by=self.request.user)
        return Response({"serializer":serializer})
```

If you do not want to render the form again, I suggest either redirect it to a different url where you get the same response in JSON format using [`JSONRenderer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#jsonrenderer). If you intend to render in the response in HTML, then I would put another context variable, like this:

```
# view
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(uploaded_by=self.request.user)
    return Response({"serializer":serializer, "data": serializer.data})

# template
{% if data %}
    {{ data }}
{{ endif }}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
        {% render_form serializer %}

    <input type="submit" value="Wyślij">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Can you advise why Im getting `    return renderer.render(serializer.data, None, {'style': style})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'` as return instead of link?

Comment: without the enctype, you would not get the file stream in the views, instead you will get a string, hence the error happened.

Comment: unfortunately enctype helped with uploading images from browser, but it returns error at the end. 
serializer.data = {'image_url': '/media/media/airplane.jpg-1678205283', 'expiring_within': 4444}
but this line
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
returns 
    return renderer.render(serializer.data, None, {'style': style})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: @djangobeginner where do you use  `serializer.data = {'image_url': '/media/media/airplane.jpg-1678205283', 'expiring_within': 4444} `?

Comment: in 
`    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(uploaded_by=self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`

Comment: is it happening only for form submission or for Postman as well?

Comment: In both ways and it looks like should work but it doesnt:/

Comment: then the problem is somewhere else, can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: I added traceback in the post as its too long for comments section

Comment: I have updated the answer with the explanation of the problem.

Comment: It is sooo weird. It return Reponse without error when I have return Response({"serializer": serializer}), but when 
return Response({"serializer": serializer.data}) i got error as earlier. I print serializer and i looks PostSerializer(data=<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['BU6SfTILf1QoP649Zh8ukbtADzspf3RFEaFiIN4VieyJTbAkR6YTITeIWPGHzROv'], 'expiring_within': ['5555'], 'image_url': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: airplane.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>):
    image_url = ImageField(max_length=100)
    expiring_within = IntegerField(validators=[<function expiring_in_validator>]) so it should totally work